# Too much recursion

Tags: javascript

can anyone tell me where the loop comes from?

**JS:**

```
if (zahl > 1) {
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').innerHTML = data_split[zahlm2];
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').onclick = getwords(zahlm2++);
}
else {
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').onclick = "";
}

if (zahl > 0) {
    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').innerHTML = data_split[zahlm1];
    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').onclick = getwords(zahlm1++);
}
else {
    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').onclick = "";
}

document.getElementById('makroclick').innerHTML = data_split[zahl];
document.getElementById('makroclick').onclick = getwords(zahl++);

document.getElementById('makroclickp1').innerHTML = data_split[zahlp1];
document.getElementById('makroclickp1').onclick = getwords(zahlp1++);
if (typeof(data_split[zahlp1]) == "undefined") {
    document.getElementById('makroclickp1').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('makroclickp1').onclick = "";
}

document.getElementById('makroclickp2').innerHTML = data_split[zahlp2];
document.getElementById('makroclickp2').onclick = getwords(zahlp2++);
if (typeof(data_split[zahlp2]) == "undefined") {
    document.getElementById('makroclickp2').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('makroclickp2').onclick = "";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="makroclickm2" onclick="" class="makroclick"></div>
<div id="makroclickm1" onclick="" class="makroclick"></div>
<div id="makroclick" onclick="getwords(0);" class="makroclick_center"></div>
<div id="makroclickp1" onclick="getwords(1);" class="makroclick"></div>
<div id="makroclickp2" onclick="getwords(2);" class="makroclick"></div>
```

(Not complete Code)
The function is called once onload.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Where\what is the `getwords` function?

Comment: I suspect that the code above _is_ the `getwords` function...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the lines like this:

```
document.getElementById('makroclickm2').onclick = getwords(zahlm2++);
```

You're assigning the `onclick` handler to the *result* of `getwords(zahlm2++)`, not to that function itself.

If, as I suspect, the code above actually is the `getwords` function, that means it's calling itself (recursively).

Instead, write:

```
document.getElementById('makroclickm2').onclick = function() {
   getwords(zahlm2++);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer the question (or even try to). However, it works to address the over-abundance of repeated code.

```
// instead of repeating the document.getElementById
// many times over...
document.getElementById('makroclickm2').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('makroclickm2').onclick = "";

// get the element once
var elm = document.getElementById('makroclickm2')
// and use it many times over
elm.innerHTML = ""
elm.onclick = null // do not use strings here
```

This will make the code much easier to follow (please use appropriate variable names).

Also, *do not use strings* with the `onclick` attribute. Use functions instead.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You also might consider using event registration rather than direct assignment.  That way you don't have to worry about accidentally overwriting anything later down the road.  @Alnitak's solution would look more like this:

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('makroclickm2');
var myFunc = function() {
    getwords(zahlm2++);
}

if (myEl.addEventListener) myEl.addEventListener("click", myFunc, false);
else if (myEl.attachEvent) myEl.attachEvent("onclick", myFunc);
else myEl.onclick = myFunc;
```

Obviously that's pretty verbose, but it would be easy to write a quick helper function takes myEl and myFunc as inputs and handles everything for you.

You can read more about event registration at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Answer (score 1):

This part might give you a ton of problems:

```
if (zahl > 1) {
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').innerHTML = data_split[zahlm2];
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').onclick = getwords(zahlm2++);
}
else {
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').onclick = "";
}

if (zahl > 0) {
    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').innerHTML = data_split[zahlm1];
    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').onclick = getwords(zahlm1++);
}
else {
    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').onclick = "";
}
```

Try using `else if` instead of another block of `if` statements. Also, I'd use `function(){}` instead of `""` (and `getwords()`, as that evaluates the function and doesn't set it to be run when the even is called):

```
if (zahl > 1) {
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').innerHTML = data_split[zahlm2];
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').onclick = function(){getwords(zahlm2++)};
} else if (zahl > 0) {
    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').onclick = null;

    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').innerHTML = data_split[zahlm1];
    document.getElementById('makroclickm1').onclick = function(){getwords(zahlm1++)};
} else {
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('makroclickm2').onclick = null;
}
```